# Karaf Deployment directory

Tags: deployment, apache-karaf

Is it possible to set a remote path (may be a FTP location) as Hot Deployment directory in Karaf environment?

I am aware of the org.apache.felix.fileinstall-deploy.cfg file under Karaf_home/etc. But this seems to be useful for changing the deployment directory to local path only.

Actually I have different Karaf installations running on different machines and I need to deploy my bundle to all instances. To avoid this I was planning to keep the deployment in some FTP location which will be treated as deployment directory for all instances.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest against using the deployment directory for productive environments. 
For your usecase I'd rather start using Karaf-Cellar and let it do the deployment across your distributed Karaf installations. This works especially good in conjunction with either a maven repository or a specialized Karaf Instance running also Karaf-Cave that will work as OBR server.